# Draw Indexed Primitives Error

Tags: c#, xna

I looked at some code from an example I found from google and implemented it into my game, but the issue is I'm getting an error: The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. Position0 is missing. I've looked at the MSDN docs and I cant see what I'm doing wrong

```
class Cube 
{
    public GraphicsDevice device;

    const int number_of_vertices = 8;
    const int number_of_indices = 36;

    private VertexBuffer vertices;
    private IndexBuffer indices;

    public Cube(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice) 
    {
        device = graphicsDevice;
    } 

    void CreateCubeVertexBuffer() 
    {
        VertexPositionColor[]cubeVertices = new VertexPositionColor[number_of_vertices];

        cubeVertices[0].Position = new Vector3(-1, -1, -1);
        cubeVertices[1].Position = new Vector3(-1, -1, 1);
        cubeVertices[2].Position = new Vector3(1, -1, 1);
        cubeVertices[3].Position = new Vector3(1, -1, -1);
        cubeVertices[4].Position = new Vector3(-1, 1, -1);
        cubeVertices[5].Position = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        cubeVertices[6].Position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        cubeVertices[7].Position = new Vector3(1, 1, -1);

        cubeVertices[0].Color = Color.Black;
        cubeVertices[1].Color = Color.Red;
        cubeVertices[2].Color = Color.Yellow;
        cubeVertices[3].Color = Color.Green;
        cubeVertices[4].Color = Color.Blue;
        cubeVertices[5].Color = Color.Magenta;
        cubeVertices[6].Color = Color.White;
        cubeVertices[7].Color = Color.Cyan;

        vertices = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration, number_of_vertices, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vertices.SetData < VertexPositionColor > (cubeVertices);
    }

    void CreateCubeIndexBuffer() {
    UInt16[]cubeIndices = new UInt16[number_of_indices];

    //bottom face
    cubeIndices[0] = 0;
    cubeIndices[1] = 2;
    cubeIndices[2] = 3;
    cubeIndices[3] = 0;
    cubeIndices[4] = 1;
    cubeIndices[5] = 2;

    //top face
    cubeIndices[6] = 4;
    cubeIndices[7] = 6;
    cubeIndices[8] = 5;
    cubeIndices[9] = 4;
    cubeIndices[10] = 7;
    cubeIndices[11] = 6;

    //front face
    cubeIndices[12] = 5;
    cubeIndices[13] = 2;
    cubeIndices[14] = 1;
    cubeIndices[15] = 5;
    cubeIndices[16] = 6;
    cubeIndices[17] = 2;

    //back face
    cubeIndices[18] = 0;
    cubeIndices[19] = 7;
    cubeIndices[20] = 4;
    cubeIndices[21] = 0;
    cubeIndices[22] = 3;
    cubeIndices[23] = 7;

    //left face
    cubeIndices[24] = 0;
    cubeIndices[25] = 4;
    cubeIndices[26] = 1;
    cubeIndices[27] = 1;
    cubeIndices[28] = 4;
    cubeIndices[29] = 5;

    //right face
    cubeIndices[30] = 2;
    cubeIndices[31] = 6;
    cubeIndices[32] = 3;
    cubeIndices[33] = 3;
    cubeIndices[34] = 6;
    cubeIndices[35] = 7;

    indices = new IndexBuffer(device, IndexElementSize.SixteenBits, number_of_indices, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
    indices.SetData < UInt16 > (cubeIndices);

    }

    public void Draw(BasicEffect effect) 
    {
        device.SetVertexBuffer(vertices);
        device.Indices = indices;

        foreach(EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) 
        {
            pass.Apply();
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, number_of_vertices, 0, number_of_indices / 3);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    cube.CreateCubeIndexBuffer();
    cube.CreateCubeVertexBuffer();

    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
        effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        effect.Texture = item.Texture;

        Matrix center = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
        Matrix scale = Matrix.CreateScale(1f);
        Matrix translate = Matrix.CreateTranslation(item.Position);

        effect.World = center * scale * translate;
        effect.View = camera.View;
        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;

        cube.Draw(effect);
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

This works but with slow FPS.

Constructor:

```
public Cube(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
{
    device = graphicsDevice;
    CreateCubeIndexBuffer();
    CreateCubeVertexBuffer();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");
    grass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("grass");

    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    Components.Add(cubes);
    cube.CreateCubeIndexBuffer();
    cube.CreateCubeVertexBuffer();

    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 50; z++)
        {
            cubes.Add(new Vector3(mapX[x], 0f, mapZ[z]), Matrix.Identity, grass);
        }
    }
}
```

This is from my main game class. This does not work and gives me the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error pointing to the line in my cube class:

```
indices = new IndexBuffer(device, IndexElementSize.SixteenBits, number_of_indices, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
```

Comment: Also note that I am calling this draw method from another class, and then calling that classes draw method in my main game class

Comment: The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. It's a shader error. It's simplest to write your own shader. But, if you use BasicEffect and draw with colors you need to set the basic effect to disable Texture and enable VertexColor. effect.TextureEnabled = false; effect.VertexColorEnabled = true; Also, you can try DrawIndexPrimitives after passing the effect if that does anything.

Comment: The BasicEffect methods are calling in another classes drawing method  which is the problem...

Comment: alright I got it to work by adding 

            cube.CreateCubeIndexBuffer();
            cube.CreateCubeVertexBuffer();
To the draw method. The fps is still under 10 because its in the draw method. The methods don't work in Init or LoadContent

Comment: You don't have to recreate the buffers "each frame", it will really drag down framerate. Also, if you're using something like using (BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect()) that will also recreate the method each draw call and reduce framerate. You might as well add CreateVertexBuffer, CreateIndexBuffer to the constructor. Otherwise there's no reason why those methods can't be called in LoadContent. from say, Game.LoadContent() { Cube cube = new Cube(graphicsDevice); cube.LoadContent() == Create vertexbuffer, indexbuffer. } I have no idea how you load the cube.

Comment: I changed the constructor to what you suggested and it still doesnt work. Check my edit to see how I load the cubes

Comment: Figured it out. But fps is still horrible. Oh well -.-

Comment: Drawing a single cube is not a demanding task for the GPU, you must check if you load any resources and dispose of them each frame - this can really drag down performance. You don't have to recreate the effect, the buffers or the object each frame - just once, at LoadContent().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for my **RenderObject** with your **Cube** added as an object to it and my own implemanation of my cube.

[XNA RenderObject with 2 types of Cubes](http://pastebin.com/Q1WQnFTC)

And this is my test game for the implementation of this.

You can simple change defaultCube = false, to try with yours. But you should resize it to 0.5, because it should be x start = -0.5f, x end = 0.5f, which is equal to 1 in size. THen you can easily just change the world scale instead.

[Test game for XNA RenderObject](http://pastebin.com/RqxM2sLM)

Since none of the above works, or because it's possible that something else in your code is hindering performance I made an example that I've used for an earlier engine.

To minimalize the amount of data of each object I simply create an abstract class that can handle just about any type of vertex, so you can create a color cube, normal cube, textured cube and so on.

First of all I have an RenderObject that stores all the fields required by a object to rendered; VertexBuffer, IndexBuffer, World matrix, BoundingBox.

And then I create a specific class that handles each type, Normal, Color, Texture. In this case I just included a version of the PrimitiveColor, which creates a Color render object.

You can even further extend this to instead of just a PrimitiveColor class, it can be a Cube class that only takes a type (Color/Normal/Texture) and you can minimalize your code for creating different types of cube, because in this case a cube will always be cube with 36 vertices and 6 faces. It's static.

Anyway, this is not required. But like any game programming or object oriented programming, a good structure is important and increases the workflow. And recreating the same properties for 100 of classes isn't that much fun. And this makes it easier to debug and find errors.

So, to simplify: RenderObject -> PrimitiveColor/PrimitiveNormal -> ColorCube / ColorNormal, you can then work with the cube instead of the rest.

I have no idea if you render "one" cube or a thousand cubes. But in my case I rendered 50*50 cubes and I had to use a frustum to cull for cubes within view of the camera to not get reduced performance. If you do this and it's still not working it's possible the error lies in another code.

This, I think is an optimal way to handle this. Because each rendered object share a buffer, a matrix and perhaps a render method (not always necessarily) and this way you can only work on the code that matters - creating the cube. It does not recreate any effects, it does not recreate any buffers after they've been initialized (although they can be changed rather quickly in the update method - I've done this with a terrain, just remember to dispose the old vertexbuffer before changing say a color in the vertices and then recreate the buffer)

My Cube, scaled correctly. Adds a white, black, white, black cube to see where they start and end.
[image]

Your Cube, scaled incorrectly. Adds your default colors.
[image]

But the important thing is that the framerate is not at fault before skipping to frustum cull the cubes. If you don't do this, it will cause framedrop. But if you only draw one cube, this should not happen.

Comment: I think it just might be my computer because I'm getting around 40 fps with the culling on. Otherwise, it works fine

Comment: You can also add a hundred cubes per vertexbuffer which also would increase draw speed. But this is perhaps for rendering far away cubes. Just add a cube to Dictionary with a IVertexType and position as the key, if the Position exits when creating a new cube, add that to the index. If you just intend to draw cubes and interact with the nearest, this is probably a good idea and draw them later. Might be more difficult if they're textured.

Comment: And as I said earlier, if it occurs with the culling on or you just draw one cube it's not your computer, it's probably something else in your code. Drawing one cube shouldn't require anything so any computer should be able to draw one without any problems or framedrop. So check your code or use some tool that checks where most of the work is done to be able to figure out where the framedrop is coming from.